# VBA code + timer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run this code but it gave me an error. The two codes separately run fine. But when I combine  the two codes they don't run fine to produce required results. Can anyone help me?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("X12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("W12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    If Bt 1.Range("Z3") = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Bt1.Range("Z3").Value = Bt 1.Range("z3").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")

    If Bt 1.Range("z3").Value <= TimeValue("00:00:10") Then
        Bt 1.Sheepes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForceColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    Else
        Bt 1.Shapes("TextBox1").Fill.ForceColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    End If
       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which "two codes" are you referring to?

Comment: Some issues here. Probably, **1.** `BT 1` should be `BT1` **2.** `.ForceColor` should be `.ForeColor` **3.** `bt1.Sheepes("TextBox 1")` should be `bt1.Shapes("TextBox 1")`

Comment: This is the first code is                                                         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("X12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("W12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: Bt 1 is the name of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the incorrect lines of code as mentioned in the comments (special thanks to @Mrig), your code is missing some checks to verify that everything is in place for the code to work. So, here is the code with the proper adjustments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim bolFound As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Checking if there is a sheet 'Bt 1'
bolFound = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Bt 1" Then bolFound = True
Next ws
If bolFound = False Then
    MsgBox "Required sheet 'Bt 1' not found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bt 1")
    'Copying the value from X12 to W12
    .Range("W12").Value2 = .Range("X12").Value2
    'Checking Z3 before proceeding
    If .Range("Z3") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Z3 is 0." & Chr(10) & _
            "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(.Range("Z3").Value) Then
        MsgBox "Z3 on the sheet 'Bt 1' is not a date / time." & Chr(10) & _
            "Therefore a second cannot be subtracted from Z3." & Chr(10) & _
            "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .Range("Z3").Value = .Range("Z3").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
    'Checking if there is a 'TextBox 1'
    bolFound = False
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        If shp.Name = "TextBox 1" Then bolFound = True
    Next shp
    If bolFound = False Then
        MsgBox "Required shape 'TextBox 1' not found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If .Range("Z3").Value <= TimeValue("00:00:10") Then
        .Shapes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        .Shapes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
End With

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Even if the code does not run as expected you should get sufficient feedback to make the necessary corrections (for the code to run).

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code run but the countdown didn't start. If you press the button the countdown start for one second and then stop immediately.

Comment: There is no countdown here. But it could be if you changed the line: `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick"` to `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Macro1"` because this is the name of your sub in the above example.